# How to access localhost on Ubuntu Linux Sub-system for Windows?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

How to access localhost on Ubuntu for Windows?

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, version 1709, OS Build 16299.125

I've installed the Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Linux Sub-system locally for Web Development purposes.

I've placed an info.php file into `\var\www\html` but when I attempt to access it at 127.0.0.1/info.php via my Browser in Windows, I receive the error:

> "This page isn’t working
>   127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

info.php has the following code in it:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

If I access 127.0.0.1 via my browser in Windows, I receive the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

And that's it. Just trying to get this working. I've installed LAMP, Composer, Platform.sh CLI and that's it on this server thus far.

*Edit* Found an error log in \var\www\html called

> C#003A#005Cxampp-new#005Cphp#005Clogs#005Cphp_error_log

Opened it and it says:

> [15-Dec-2017 10:18:41 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
>
> [15-Dec-2017 10:18:41 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/info.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Not sure what that means. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why this was happening. Ran:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 var
```

And that worked. I **DO NOT** RECOMMEND DOING THIS ON A PRODUCTION SYSTEM. This is a local Development System!

Comment: Check the permissions of each level of the directory tree for `/var/www/html/info.php` to make sure that whatever account Apache is running in has access. I was writing this comment when your answer appeared: it's unnecessarily drastic, and is definitely not recommended, as it will remove any extended attributes (SUID, etc). If you want to be so drastic, at least use `ugo+rwx` instead of `777` and log the changes with `-v`, so that you can undo them later with a bit of scripting on the log file. I doubt that you will need write access, nor to directories outside `/var/html`.